# Remoting from iOS to Java/Spring backend

Tags: java, ios, json, spring, backend

In our application we have an Adobe Flex client that communicates to our Java/Spring backend via a facade (using AMF) that is exposed via Spring.

Any recommendations on how I could leverage this facade to make remote calls from iOS? Note that I would prefer backend frameworks that would be reusable from other clients (Android, etc).

I hear about JSON & RESTful web services. Would there be a way to rather easily get existing facade services to be exposed as RESTFul web services that uses JSON for object serialization?

Or would you recommend something different?

Any information and/or pointers will be appreciated!

Update:

So we have one option so far for this: JSON requests and responses via Spring

Anybody want to suggest any other ways?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spring supports JSON requests and responses (see for instance, [this articl](http://springinpractice.com/2012/02/22/supporting-xml-and-json-web-service-endpoints-in-spring-3-1-using-responsebody/)e from the Spring In Practice blog), largely through the use of annotations.

While I don't think that it is likely that you'll be able to go through your existing AMF facade, I think that it should probably be pretty straight-forward to create a JSON-over-HTTP facade using the same underlying Spring controllers (assuming that you're using Spring MVC).

Edit: Whether the JSON-over-HTTP facade that you create is truly RESTful depends largely on your implementation.

Comment: The actual facade services are just Java interfaces with implementations that sit behind GraniteDS. The implementation classes have some GraniteDS annotations on the methods to expose them and the entity beans have an annotation that externalizes the entity properties. I think the facade services & entity beans should be reusable with the Spring stuff you are talking about, not?

Comment: Yes, exactly. You should be able to build a Spring MVC / JSON interface on the same services that you use for AMF